# Get user manager at extension class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm migrating my ASP.net MVC project to core version. I have an extension class with method, that returns user's name by user id (Guid).

```
public static class IdentityHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetUserName(this HtmlHelper html, string id)
    {
        var manager = HttpContext.Current
            .GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();

        return new MvcHtmlString(manager.FindByIdAsync(id).Result.UserName);
    }
}
```

As I'm rewriting this to .NET Core, I don't know how to get user manager instance here. Normally I would just inject this through DI, but I don't know what to do as I'm using extension method so I can't inject it.

How can I get `UserManager` in static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have changed in the new version. Access the current `HttpContext` via the `HtmlHelper.ViewContext` and from there you should be able to get access to an `IServiceProvider` that can be used to resolve services.

```
public static class IdentityHelpers {
    public static MvcHtmlString GetUserName(this HtmlHelper html, string id) {
        HttpContext context = html.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        IServiceProvider services = context.RequestServices;
        var manager = services.GetService<AppUserManager>();

        return new MvcHtmlString(manager.FindByIdAsync(id).Result.UserName);
    }
}
```